# gregorian calendars package on golang

Tags: go

I m wrking on a project, and I want to make a date variable with the gregorian calendar in goLang, I've searched about it, but i didn't found an answer
here is what i want to do with in golang in a java type code

```
try {
                final Calendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
                gc.setTime(simpleDateFormat.parse(callEndDateTime));
                gc.add(Calendar.SECOND, -1 * duration);
                callStartDateTime = simpleDateFormat.format(gc.getTime());
            } catch (final ParseException parseException) {
                LOGGER.error("Couldn't parse the given date: " + callEndDateTime, parseException);
                callStartDateTime = null;
            }
```

thanks for helping me!

Comment: By the way, the troublesome `Calendar` class is now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes such as `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it as a string variable and than parse it.

```
string strDate = "07 31 2017"; //example
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
Date date = df.parse(strDate);
Calendar cal =  new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(date);
```

Comment: but i want the code in golang not java

Comment: You can use the Time.String() method to convert a time.Time to a string.
t := time.Now()
fmt.Println(t.String())

Comment: and it will show as a simpleDate???

Comment: fmt.Println(t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))

Answer (score 0):

The time package always assumes you're working with a Gregorian calendar, [as shown in the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)

Now if you want to parse a date time in golang it's rather simple but you have to keep in mind that the date parser isn't using the "standard" way of defining date formats.

You can see an example of how to use the time parser in [the official documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse)

```
const longForm = "Jan 2, 2006 at 3:04pm (MST)"
t, _ := time.Parse(longForm, "Feb 3, 2013 at 7:54pm (PST)")
fmt.Println(t)
```

That's how you parse a string into a date in go. Converting a date to a string is even simpler :

```
t.Format("2006-01-02")
```

See the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) for more information